# Is there a better way to count occurrence of char in a string?

Tags: perl, sh

I felt there must a better way to count occurrence instead of writing a sub in perl, shell in Linux.

```
#/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
return 1 unless $0 eq __FILE__;
main() if $0 eq __FILE__;
sub main{
    my $str = "ru8xysyyyyyyysss6s5s";
    my $char = "y";
    my $count = count_occurrence($str, $char);
    print "count<$count> of <$char> in <$str>\n";
}
sub count_occurrence{
    my ($str, $char) = @_;
    my $len = length($str);
    $str =~ s/$char//g;
    my $len_new = length($str);
    my $count = $len - $len_new;
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Counting the occurences of a character in a string can be performed with one line in Perl (as compared to your 4 lines).  There is no need for a sub (although there is nothing wrong with encapsulating functionality in a sub).  From [perlfaq4 "How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = "ru8xysyyyyyyysss6s5s";
my $char = "y";
my $count = () = $str =~ /\Q$char/g;
print "count<$count> of <$char> in <$str>\n";
```

Answer (score 17):

If the character is constant, the following is best:

```
my $count = $str =~ tr/y//;
```

If the character is variable, I'd use the following:

```
my $count = length( $str =~ s/[^\Q$char\E]//rg );
```

I'd only use the following if I wanted compatibility with versions of Perl older than 5.14 (as it is slower and uses more memory):

```
my $count = () = $str =~ /\Q$char/g;
```

The following uses no memory, but might be a bit slow:

```
my $count = 0;
++$count while $str =~ /\Q$char/g;
```

Answer (score 5):

In a *beautiful** Bash/Coreutils/Grep one-liner:

```
$ str=ru8xysyyyyyyysss6s5s
$ char=y
$ fold -w 1 <<< "$str" | grep -c "$char"
8
```

Or maybe

```
$ grep -o "$char" <<< "$str" | wc -l
8
```

The first one works only if the substring is just one character long; the second one works only if the substrings are non-overlapping.

<sub>* Not really.</sub>

Comment: both works well, I added  them to my tools box, first time heard the cmd fold, appreciated!

Comment: @gliang: It's a bit like the `split //` of Bash, I only discovered it recently as well. Glad you find them useful!

Answer (score 3):

[toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197758/toolic) has given a correct answer, but you might consider not hardcoding your values to make the program reusable.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 <text> <characters>" if @ARGV < 1;
my $search = shift;                    # the string you are looking for
my $str;                               # the input string
if (@ARGV && -e $ARGV[0] || !@ARGV) {  # if str is file, or there is no str
    local $/;                          # slurp input
    $str = <>;                         # use diamond operator
} else {                               # else just use the string
    $str = shift;
}
my $count = () = $str =~ /\Q$search\E/gms;
print "Found $count of '$search' in '$str'\n";
```

This will allow you to use the program to count for the occurrence of a character, or a string, inside a string, a file, or standard input. For example:

```
count.pl needles haystack.txt
some_process | count.pl foo
count.pl x xyzzy
```

Comment: what is the gms for? g - for all  occurence, m for match, s for ?

Comment: @gliang: "Treat string as single line", i.e., `.` matches newlines, which it normally doesn't, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Comment: Benjamin, thanks, it is not what i thought it is. I will read the document again.

Comment: @gliang No, `m` is multiline, meaning newline is matched by `^` and `$` (and equivalent), and `s` like Benjamin said makes `.` also match newline. They are not strictly needed in your example, and `\Q` excludes the use of the `.` metacharacter anyway. But since we do not know what your input will be, this is a safer way.